# Loki - how to filter on second field and expand context automatically

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

When I run a search in Loki, I am able to find what I am looking for by using a query as follows:

```
{app="my-cool-app"} |= `error`
```

When I look at the results for this, I can see that when I expand the context, I see another field that I would like to filter on as well and jump directly to that line, for example 'error2'. However, if I run the query from grafana as follows:

{app="my-cool-app"} |= `error` |= `error2`

I get no result. Should I not get the result that I was able to find manually via this query ? How can I acheive what I am trying to do, is it even possible ?

Also, since my message is EXTREMELY long, I dont want to have to hit 'Show Context' and load 10 more lines at a time, this is very slow and error prone. Is there a way to view the fully expanded context all at once ? Or even to download it locally and search it ?

Comment: Don't know, [seems to be working](https://play.grafana.org/explore?schemaVersion=1&panes=%7B%22ym9%22:%7B%22datasource%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22,%22queries%22:%5B%7B%22refId%22:%22A%22,%22expr%22:%22%7Bfilename%3D%5C%22%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fnginx%2Faccess.log%5C%22%7D%20%7C%3D%20%5C%22Mozilla%5C%22%20%7C%3D%20%5C%22Android%5C%22%22,%22queryType%22:%22range%22,%22datasource%22:%7B%22type%22:%22loki%22,%22uid%22:%22ac4000ca-1959-45f5-aa45-2bd0898f7026%22%7D,%22editorMode%22:%22code%22%7D%5D,%22range%22:%7B%22from%22:%22now-1h%22,%22to%22:%22now%22%7D%7D%7D&orgId=1)